# count days in month

Tags: php, mysqli

I have code that counts working days in month .
If in month there is 1 period everything is counted good.

But if in month (this case August) is more than one period it doesn't work

```
Dates example <br>
2016-08-02 - 2016-08-04 (3 working days)<br>
then <br>
2016-08-08 - 2016-08-10 (3 working days)<br>
and 2016-08-24 - 2016-09-02 (6 working days)<br>
```

So it would be 12 working days in August

Here is my mysqli query:

```
$getaways =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM employeesAbsence 
                                  WHERE workerID='".$row['worker']."' 
                                  AND fromDate LIKE  '%2016-08%' 
                                  AND toDate LIKE  '%2016-08%'); 
$aways_row = mysqli_fetch_array($getaways);
$fDate = $aways_row['fromDate'];
$tDate = $aways_row['toDate'];
```

and here is php:

```
function get_days($start, $end)
{  
    $begin = new DateTime( $start );
    $end   = new DateTime( $end );
    //$end   = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); //add one day so as to include the end date of our range

    $total_days = 0;
    //this will calculate total days from monday to friday in above date range
    for( $i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify( '+1 day' ) )
    {
        // Check that the date is between Monday and Friday and only in August
        if( ( $i->format( 'N' ) >= 1 && $i->format( 'N') <= 5 ) && $i->format( 'm' ) == '08' )
        {
            $total_days++;
        }
    }
    return $total_days;
}

$total = 0;
$total += get_days( $fDate, $tDate);
```

> This code returns `3` as the number of working days

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Well as one of your tests is `$i->format( 'm' ) == '08'` the dates not in August will not be counted

Comment: I assume the missing `"` at the end of your query is just a TYPO?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i m just working with August now will change that later! also yes that was just a typo!

Comment: @RiggsFolly yep its DATE and if i remove to date nothing still changes

Comment: Suggested query change: `MONTH(fromDate) = 8 AND MONTH(toDate) = 8`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried this Suggested query do same job for now

Comment: this is fromDate 2016-08-24 and this is toDate 2016-09-02 they are returned as you see

Comment: @RiggsFolly you dont get the point . ..That period ends in 09 but i need count every working day that is in 08 . So if it ends in 09 then the last counted day will be 31st August if it a working day!

Comment: I understand that, but I dont see how that row could actually be returned from that query

Comment: each period is new line in database for current user

Comment: It just stops at first period it dont take next period

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. What answer are you getting?

Comment: I get 3 working days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I get the issue now, you are getting more than one row returned from the query but you are only using the first row in your calculation.

You need to loop over the 3 rows returned by the query.

```
function get_days( $start, $end )
{  
    $begin = new DateTime( $start );
    $end   = new DateTime( $end );

    $total_days = 0;
    //this will calculate total days from monday to friday in above date range
    for( $i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify( '+1 day' ) ) {
        // Check that the date is between Monday and Friday and only in August
        if( ( $i->format( 'N' ) >= 1 && $i->format( 'N') <= 5 ) && $i->format( 'm' ) == '08' ) {
            $total_days++;
        }
    }
    return $total_days;
}

$getaways =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM employeesAbsence 
                                   WHERE workerID='".$row['worker']."' 
                                   AND MONTH(fromDate) = 8 
                                   AND MONTH(toDate) = 8"); 

if ( ! $getaways ) {
    echo mysqli_error($getaways);
    exit;
}

// just check how many row you get back
echo 'Query generated ' . mysqli_num_rows($getaways) . ' rows';

$total = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getaways) ){
    $total += get_days($row['fromDate'], $row['toDate']);
}
echo $total;
```

To get the results you are suggestiong that you want, try changing the query to

```
$getaways =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM employeesAbsence 
                                   WHERE workerID='".$row['worker']."' 
                                   AND MONTH(fromDate) = 8");
```

This will then return you all rows where the holiday started in August regardless of when the holiday finished.

Comment: I added a print of the number of rows returned by your query. Maybe that will throw some light on an issue in the query!

Comment: where is record there 1 where are no records there 0 is returned

Comment: So I guess the query has an error. See the error checking code I added

Comment: I dont think your query is returning what you think it is returning, which leads me back to my other comments above, I dont think the query will return this row `2016-08-24 - 2016-09-02` as `AND MONTH(toDate) = 8` will stop that

Comment: Strange there are no error .maybe i could not asc for a date in querry but somehow filter that in php?

Comment: See suggested query change. So you get all the holidays that started in August, regadless of when they finished

Comment: Did that query change give you more than one row in the result set?

Comment: Still the same i m kind new at this so i cant figure this out!it needed to work!

Comment: Can you run your query in phpMyAdmin or something like that and post the result that you get in your questions please

Comment: I did got 3 records  as should be: Showing rows 0 - 2 (3 total, Query took 0.0008 sec) [workerID: 09429 - 09429]

Comment: Then I have no idea, as I cannot actually see anything myself. I would need to see what is really happening to be able to be more help

Comment: Ok i believe your answer is correct so i will accept it!Thanks for help!